# JBoss EAP 6.1 does not start in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

After a lot of fixes and installations, I finally managed to install JBoss in Eclipse Mars running JRE 8. I created a Runtime Server environment which I have in my D drive and created a server in Eclipse. But when I try to start the server, it does not go beyond three lines of INFO . I googled and could not find any info regarding the same.

There are no stack traces or log which I can check to address the problem. I tried starting the server in `cmd` and it gives me the same three lines.

These are the line after which the JBoss server does not do anything:

```
18:58:05,721 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.Final-redhat-1
18:58:05,894 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
18:58:05,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) starting
```

Please help me on how to get this working.

Comment: Did you install the Jboss Tools plugin, specifically the JBossAS tool that is part of it?

Comment: I have installed both Jboss Tools as well as RedHat JBoss Developer Studio

Comment: Does the server start at all when you try to run it outside of Eclipse?

Comment: No. I tried to run the server via cmd by calling standalone.bat still does not work

Comment: Seems more like a question for Redhat support then. As asked this question is a complete red herring, it has nothing to do with Eclipse at all.

Comment: hmm ok.. Will open a thread there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I was using a JRE. JBoss needed a JDK to work properly. Once I changed it, the server was able to startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't modify any server configuration in/after the installation wizard, you can try validating that ports 4447, 8080, 9990 and 9999 are not in use by another application.

Another alternative is to download the latest EAP version.
I installed EAP-6.4.0.GA with java 1.8.0_45 and no issues.

Comment: Actually it was the problem with the Java Environment. It needs a JDK whereas I was using a JRE. Once I changed it, it worked fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ViChU seems like an odd turn of events, I'd expect a startup error, not a hanging server. Sounds more like the runtime itself was busted.